# British SAS Emotes: Are we rushing in, or are we going sneaky-____ like?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Simple question: when the British SAS emote in Counter-Stike : Global Offensive, what do they say?

"Are we rushing in, or are we going sneaky-____ like?"

Is it sneaky-deaky, sneaky-beaky, or sneaky-peaky?

I've found multiple unreliable sources that claim to know the answer, but I am skeptical, especially since the sources do not agree with each other.  The SAS wiki, editable by the community, is not a reliable source in my mind (http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/SAS), and neither is Urban Dictionary (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sneaky-beaky).

What do you guys think?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to learn?  I don't see any problem being solved here.

Comment: SAS wiki = editable by community so not a good source. Solution, ask the community what they think it is?

Comment: If you must know, I'm trying to settle an argument.  @PeterL The wiki mentions sneaky-peeky and sneaky-peaky.  Normally I wouldn't think too much of a spelling mistake, but in this case, it seems to indicate uncertainty over what they actually say.  Not to mention one says "Are we rushin' in? Or going sneaky peaky like?" and the other says "We rushin' in, or we doin' sneaky-peeky like.", so the wiki even contradicts itself on the surrounding words.  It has lost credibility on the issue in my book, so yes, I'd rather ask Stackexchange users.

Comment: I'll add as a comment then because it's not authoritative, but at least "peek" is a real word that would make sense in context -- being stealthy (sneaky) and looking into rooms (peeking) rather than just running in. The alternative (peaky) is a real word as well but has nothing to do with the context given. Google search for either term returns results, but "sneaky-peaky" is a lot more UD pages where "sneaky-peeky" shows a book using that spelling and an NY Post article. Short of finding the script given to the voice actor, I don't know how authoritatively this can be answered.

Comment: If you google "Sneaky Beaky", "Sneaky Deaky", or "Sneaky Peaky", Google actually offers an autocomplete option for all of them that adds a "Like" onto the end.  "Sneaky Beaky" also has a surprising number of results.  That said, my original choice, "Sneaky Deaky", probably has the least number of results.

Comment: @MikeS you should think on the meaning of the phrase too, they're not just random words thrown out, i think that PeterL explained very well that chioce of words that is also on the wiki page, and i still don't get it what further proof would you actually need.

Comment: This is the best response I could have hoped for!  Developer response = conclusive.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The accent makes it difficult to determine what's being said without having the actual voice actor on hand.  However, using Google we *can* determine what the correct phrase is *(and therefore, what he most-likely meant to say)*.

---

Google gives the following estimated result-sizes when searching for these phrases *(in quotes)*:

- **sneaky peeky**: 85,000
- **sneaky peaky**: 50,900
- **sneaky beeky**: 12,200
- **sneaky deaky**: 5,900
- **sneaky deeky**: 1,090
- **sneaky beaky**: 463

Additionally, [google n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sneaky+peeky%2Csneaky+peaky%2Csneaky+beaky%2C+sneaky+beeky%2Csneaky+deaky%2C+sneaky+deeky&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows that only **one** of these phrases is used in real literature *(or at least, the literature they have indexed)*:

[image: Sneaky Peeky graph]

Therefore, it's easy to conclude that **the correct phrase is "sneaky peeky"**.

---

**[Edit April 2015]**  People have pointed out that there's now a CS:GO sticker with the phrase "sneaky beaky" on it.

[image: Sneaky Beaky]

According to the author of that sticker, [it's supposed to be a joke](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/discussion/232510527/558749824318039165/#c558749824361516732):

> Haha, it's "sneaky peaky/peeky".
>   [..]
>   This is just a play on words, because a) it's really hard to tell what the hell they're saying in game; b) chickens are a huge part of cs and c) chickens are sneaky, and they have beaks... sneaky beaky. Yeeea.

However, because of that sticker, *"sneaky beaky"* appears to be becoming an 'acceptable' alternative to *"sneaky peeky"*.  Google's estimated result size for "sneaky beaky" has gone up from 463 *(Feb 2014)* to 101,000 *(April 2015)*!

Comment: Relevant: https://twitter.com/StealthMountain/favorites

Comment: This is probably as close as we can get to an official answer and the references/graph are solid.  Very nice!

Answer (score 5):

It's sneaky peeky, its a Scottish accent and to any Scottish person it's as clear as day. The Sneaky 'Beaky' sticker is a joke, with a bird on the sticker....

Answer (score 4):

It's sneaky beaky. They released stickers with the quote

Comment: -1 [The author of that sticker has stated it's a joke](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/discussion/232510527/558749824318039165/) *(and even linked to this thread :D)*

Comment: Yes. Just scroll down a little and you will see the (probably) correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the wiki states pretty clearly :

> ```
> "We rushin' in, or we doin' sneaky-peeky like." 
> ―SAS
> ```

[**Source:** SAS wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/SAS)

EDIT:

I understand that the wiki is not necessarily a reliable source but where can you find another source other than the audio played in the game or the game's wiki ? I think that this is pretty much a reliable source.

Comment: "The SAS wiki, editable by the community, is not a reliable source in my mind"

Comment: Please include a link to the source.

Comment: @galacticninja i think that the source was included by the author himself

Comment: You may be right, you might not be able to find another reliable source, but the wiki seems questionable at best.

Answer (score -3):

sneaky-beaky. You can hear that B well in quote.